Unable to connect my node.js application to remote db server
I am trying to connect my node.js application to the remote postgresql db which is running on Azure VM in Linux OS.
When i use PGAdmin on my system and try to connect to the remote postgresql db using ssltunneling then i am getting connected to server and i am able to see the list of dbs in it.
From PGAdmin i can create and remove dbs to the remote server and the change are getting reflected in the server.
But when i am using the same credentials in my node.js app then i am getting authentication error like this error: password authentication failed for user "postgres".
On server side i have made changes in  postgresql.conf`
i have changed listen_addresses from 'localhost' to '*'

# - Connection Settings -

listen_addresses = '*'          # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                                        # comma-separated list of addresses;
                                        # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                                        # (change requires restart)
port = 5433                     # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100                   # (change requires restart)
#reserved_connections = 0               # (change requires restart)
#superuser_reserved_connections = 3     # (change requires restart)
unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql' # comma-separated list of directories
                                        # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_group = ''                 # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_permissions = 0777         # begin with 0 to use octal notation
                                        # (change requires restart)
#bonjour = off                          # advertise server via Bonjour


this is my pg_hba.conf
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local     all            postgres        peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local     all            all             peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host     all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host     all             all             ::0/0                   md5
#all ips
host     all             all             all                     md5



If you're Azure VM requires SSL, you need to include the ssl configuration for pg library.

error -  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
Mostly the above error comes because of the mismatch of connection string in node.js.
PostgreSQL connection setup in Node.js using pg:
const { Pool } = require('pg');

const pool = new Pool({
  user: 'postgres',
  host: 'your-remote-host-ip',
  database: 'your_database_name',
  password: 'your_password',
  port: 5433,
  ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false }, // Set to true or false as needed
});

pool.connect((err, client, release) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.error('Error acquiring client', err.stack);
  }
  console.log('Connected to the database!');
  release();
});


Check that the entry for host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5 comes after the local all postgres peer entry, as the configuration is read in order, and conflicting entries can sometimes cause issues.


